# Not able to Publish the ASP.Net app in Visual studio

Tags: c#, angular, webpack, asp.net-core, angular5

I am trying to publish the app from Visual-Studio but I am getting the error:

> The command  "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod"
>   exited with code 1. first azure app 
>   C:...\firstazureapp
>   C:...firstazureapp\firstazureapp.csproj 497

I have followed this Article 
[Getting Started With Angular 5 And ASP.NET Core](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-angular5-and-asp-net-core/)

Everything is working fine but at publish time only I am getting the error.

I have run this command In the node modules folder and it is giving these issue

> C:\Users\acer\source\repos\testfromcmd>node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod
>
> Hash: 40bd2f76867df4f7cc31ffb9aab17185511f568b
>
> Version: webpack 2.5.1
>
> Child
>       Hash: 40bd2f76867df4f7cc31
>       Time: 26026ms
>                Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
>       main-client.js  1.73 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main-client

```
ERROR in main-client.js from UglifyJs
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined
>           at filterdFiles.forEach (C:\Users\acer\source\repos\testfromcmd\node_modules\webpack\lib\optimize\UglifyJsPlugin.js:81:21)
>           at Array.forEach ()
>           at Compilation.compilation.plugin (C:\Users\acer\source\repos\testfromcmd\node_modules\webpack\lib\optimize\UglifyJsPlugin.js:40:18)
>           at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (C:\Users\acer\source\repos\testfromcmd\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:142:13)
>           at self.applyPluginsAsync.err (C:\Users\acer\source\repos\testfromcmd\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:635:10)
>           at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (C:\Users\acer\source\repos\testfromcmd\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:131:46)
>           at sealPart2 (C:\Users\acer\source\repos\testfromcmd\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:631:9)
>           at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (C:\Users\acer\source\repos\testfromcmd\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:131:46)
>           at Compilation.seal (C:\Users\acer\source\repos\testfromcmd\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:579:8)
>           at C:\Users\acer\source\repos\testfromcmd\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:493:16
>           at C:\Users\acer\source\repos\testfromcmd\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:225:11
>           at _addModuleChain (C:\Users\acer\source\repos\testfromcmd\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:481:11)
>           at processModuleDependencies.err (C:\Users\acer\source\repos\testfromcmd\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:452:13)
>           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:150:11)
>   Child
>       Hash: ffb9aab17185511f568b
>       Time: 26026ms
>                Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
>       main-server.js  2.04 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main-server

Comment: Get more information. Open the Output window and select the Build stream.

Comment: So, open a shell window, change to the project directory that contains your webpack config, and run `node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod`. What errors do you see? Edit your question to provide this info, and there will be more to go on.

Comment: I have updated my code

Comment: I solved my problem by changing the uglify version from 3.0.23 to 2.8.23 and this works for me thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by changing the uglify version from 3.0.23 to 2.8.23 and this works for me thanks for help